# How to go to website from list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, random

Let's say I have a list such as

```
var websites = {
    website1.com,
    website2.com,
    website3.com,
};
```

When I press something, such as a `<a>` tag, choose from the list of websites, and automatically go there. I don't want any customization, repeating pages are fine, I just want something basic and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make it a complete URL and set `window.location` equal to that URL.

Also, for a simple list, an array like `[1, 2, 3]` can be easier to work with than an object like `{1,2,3}`. Try this:

```js
var websites = [
"website1.com",
"website2.com",
"website3.com"
];

var exitURL = "http://" + websites[i];

window.location = exitURL;
```